# how can i sort in bash the first column but ignore any other column in order

Tags: linux, bash, sorting, git-bash

I want to sort in bash by only the first column and keep the order. 
for example:

```
5 6
4 8
2 9
5 4
```

I want to get

```
2 9
4 8
5 6
5 4
```

but I am getting

```
2 9
4 8
5 4
5 6
```

can I keep it in order with the sort command? or in any other way?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/33362/how-to-unix-sort-by-one-column-only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the stable sort:

```
sort -nsk1,1
```

- `-n` sort numerically
- `-k1,1` sorts by the first column ("from the first to the first")
- `-s` means "stable", i.e. keep the input order in case of a draw

Note that not all implementations of `sort` support the `-s`, as it's not mentioned in the POSIX specification.

Comment: Interesting. I wasn't sure how reliable this is. It's not well explained in the man page. Maybe it's worth to mention that `-s` is not posix.